# Angular build process with multiple projects and libraries

Tags: angular, typescript, build, configuration

The other day I've deployed the first version of our front-end and while setting everything up, I've been quite confused on the build process.
Most Angular apps don't really bother with using the workspace feature as the only reason for doing so would be if you're making multiple separate apps that share code via a library for reasons such as wanting to physically separate the client UI and the back-office UI.

Until now I've been following a very well written article about Angular library projects:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

Unfortunately like with most articles, the build process other then the one concerning the library project itself is pretty vague. I did manage have everything up and running with the following commands (I made a script in the scripts section of package.json):

```
ng build my-lib-project-name && ng build && ng build my-ui-project-name --output-hashing=all --configuration=demo
```

Then I just copy the contents of dist/my-ui-project-name to the server and its done (the actual build process is on the cloud server as well).

What I find weird though is having to do a second ng build just before I ng build my main project that imports my library or my main project build won't be able to find my library project.
This of course isn't necessary with ng serve and only building the lib works just fine.

Also Im having an issue with the --prod flag as apparently one of my components can't be found:

```
ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class SideNavMenuItemComponent in <my_path_to_project>/projects/my-lib-project-name/src/lib/layout/sidebar/side-nav-menu/side-nav-menu-item.component.ts! Add SideNavMenuItemComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

This of course only occurs during --prod build and works just fine without the flag or in ng serve as I've obviously included it into an NgModule.

This leads me to think that my build process is probably not the best. Does anyone have a build process setup for their multi-project Angular app ? With multiple environment management as a cherry on top ?

I've only added some scripts to the main package.json and my angular.json has default build config in it. Also, we're currently still on Angular 7 and we'll be moving to 8 in the near future.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Fasco figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out. Basically the issue was with imports.
I import a lot components/services/etc from my my-lib-project-name and the right way to do so is:

```
import {SomeService, ISomeInterface} from 'my-lib-project-name';
```

But sometimes my IDE (webstorm) automatically imports stuff with the wrong path:

```
import {SomeService} from '../../../../../../../my-lib-project-name/src/lib/some-path/some-service.service';
```

This works just fine with ng serve as serve just gets the files directly from the project files so any relative paths from one project will definitely work with the other (unless you move stuff). Build on the other hand makes builds you projects and puts stuff in a dist folder, so any relative paths don't mean anything anymore.

In conclusion, just do a project wide search for any long path containing strings like this `'../../my-lib-project-name'` and replace those by `'my-lib-project-name'`.